# How to prevent XSS attack such as onmouseover in mvc?

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, xss, owasp

Lately, a penetration test is done using OWAPS ZAP tool in my application. I have not much knowledge of security testing. They found some vulnerability that is XSS Cross-Site Scripting (Persistent).

In the application, there is a simple module that contains both getting some HTML content from users and according to content users can messaging with each other. I understand the vulnerability that occurs while getting HTML codes from users and decode them with `@Html.Raw(content)`. HtmlSanitizer fixed this kind of attack such as alerting with using a script (<script alert(1); /script>) in my application.

But I confused at some point. The other vulnerability arose while getting user's messages. It attacks with sending message 'onMouseOver=alert(1);' as input. My application takes this input as normal text and shows the message as text. I showed the messages also with razor-like `@message.content` and I didn't use any @Html attributes.

I don't understand the vulnerabilities sending onMouseOver=alert(1); as input. What could be the problem?